# How do I remove a class when clicking on another element or outside of element (angular 4)?

Tags: angular

I have many of these on my page to target the parent div of a bootstrap input group so I can apply styling on focus of form control, I cannot target the input-add-on with css because it comes before the form control.

I need to add a class on the selected item only but how to do I remove it when clicked on outside or on another div? I can do this in javascript but not sure how to do it it angular 4. It would be better to add some sort of global function but this is how far I got. Still learning. Thanks in advance

```
<div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem === 'item1'}" 
                                          (click)="selectedItem = 'item1'"> 
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="capacity-addon">%</span>
  <input name="capacity" formControlName="capacity" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: <div class="input-group" [ngClass]="{'active': selectedItem === 'item3'}" (click)="selectedItem = 'item3'"> 
  <span class="input-group-addon" id="capacity-addon">%</span>
  <input name="capacity" formControlName="capacity" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="e.g. 80">
</div>

Comment: Maybe this could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479457/angular-2-4-set-focus-on-input-element

Comment: as you are new : http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

one way you can do it like this , Create `directive` and attached with your element.

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Output, EventEmitter, HostListener} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[clickOutside]'
})
export class ClickOutsideDirective {
    constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef) {
    }

    @Output()
    public clickOutside = new EventEmitter();

    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event.target'])
    public onClick(targetElement) {
        const clickedInside = this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(null);
        }
    }
}
```

Directive make use of native `ElementRef(directive associated element) & HostListener(document)` and dose task , if you want to read you can follow this post : [Angular 2: A Simple Click Outside Directive](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/angular-2-a-simple-click-outside-directive/)