# How can I set focus always on input in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I want to control my application JUST from one text input, so I need to have focus ALWAYS on it (to prevent users from accidentally losing this focus by clicking somewhere on page etc.). And to be fair I don't even know how can I do this.

I tried to use html's autofocus on this input and then check if it loses it's focus. But I don't know, how to "revive" this focus on it. This is my code:

HTML file:

```
<div fxLayout fxLayoutAlign="center">
  <div fxFlex="80" class="operations">

    <div class="H-opt">Użytkownik: <span>{{ActualUser}}</span></div>
    <div class="H-opt">Magazyn źródłowy: <span></span></div>
    <div class="H-opt">Magazyn docelowy: <span></span></div>

    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="codeExec" (focusout)="reviveFocus()" (keyup.enter)="execAction($event.target.value)" autofocus >

  </div>

</div>
```

TS file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../../shared/services/auth.service';
import { DatabaseService } from '../../../shared/services/database.service';
import { MatSnackBar, MatDialog } from '@angular/material';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cbisgate-userdash',
  templateUrl: './cbisgate-userdash.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cbisgate-userdash.component.css']
})
export class CbisgateUserdashComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private authService: AuthService, private databaseService: DatabaseService, public snackBar: MatSnackBar) { }

  codeExec: string = "";

  ActualUser;
  DepotFrom;
  DepotTo;

  clearCodeExec() {
    this.codeExec = "";
  }

  reviveFocus() {
    console.log("I'm trying to revive this input!");
  }

  execAction(code) {
    this.ActualUser = code;
    console.log(code);
    this.clearCodeExec();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

How can I use this reviveFocus function, is there any way to make focus again on this input? Or it's other way to do the "all-time" focus?

Comment: You can to refocus see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44479457/angular-2-4-set-focus-on-input-element. But keep in note that forcing the user to stay in the input is [bad idea](https://uxplanet.org/7-deadly-ux-sins-and-how-to-avoid-them-f47292e1f5dd).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the `(blur)` event binding instead. I think that is the right binding keyword when it comes to blurred/losing focus events.

First, we bind the `blur` event to the `onBlur()` method. Next, we set an template reference variable on the input element.

```
<input matInput #yourInput (blur)="onBlur($event)">
```

And on your component.ts, we will set the element to focus whenever `onBlur` is triggered.

```
@ViewChild('yourInput', {static: false}) yourInput: ElementRef;

onBlur(event) {
  this.yourInput.nativeElement.focus()
}
```

I have made a demo over [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ifyn7p?file=app/input-overview-example.ts).

Comment: What if we want to prevent lose focus, when a specific button (not anywhere in the page) is clicked?

Comment: And here is the answer to my questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147275/hide-element-on-blur-of-input-except-when-element-is-clicked